# Ajax request not working on datatable pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

In my `Laravel` web application I am using `datatable` to show data. My table has 3 actions to `view`, `edit` and `delete`.
For edit and view I am using `Bootstrap 4` modal.

Here is a view of data table..
[image]

Here is my ajax request code to edit on modal:

```
$.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:"{{route('user.edit')}}",
      data:{'id':user_id},
      success:function(data){
        var role;
        if(data.role_id == 1){
            role = 'Admin';
        }else if(data.role_id == 2){
            role = 'Seller';
        }else{
            role = 'Publisher';
        }
        $(header).empty();
        $(header).append('<h3>'+data.details.name+'\'s details</h3>');
        $('#name').empty();
        $('#name').val(data.details.name);
        $('#email').empty();
        $('#email').val(data.details.email);
        $('#contact').empty();
        $('#contact').val(data.details.contact);
        $('#address').empty();
        $('#address').val(data.details.address);
        $('#user_id').empty();
        $('#user_id').val(data.details.id);
        $.each(data.roles, function(index,val){
            if(data.details.role_id == val.id)
                var selected = 'selected';
            $('#role').append('<option '+selected+' value="'+val.id+'">'+val.role_name+'</option>');

        });
    }
});
```

Now everything works fine for the first page. But when I search something in `datatable` or go to another page through pagination, my ajax request does not work. I am using class to call the ajax request. When I go to another page or search a data and click on edit, Only the modal opens the ajax request does not initiate and it shows empty modal.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does it say anything in the console? Also, remove the `empty()` calls. They are redundant.

Comment: are you doing this in a blade?  a Vue front end?  Laravel actually has a datatable package that is super simple/easy.  http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation . If you are in a blade just send all the data back from the controller attached to a blade, loop through it build a table that call jQuery on it.

Comment: @Mark Walet Console is clean. When I go to other page the ajax just does not activate....

Comment: @Brad I am using Blade. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. But is there any fix for my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.your_button', function(){
   //code for action
});
```

event handler only handle to those elements which exists in the dom when the code was executed so need to use delegation based event handler. try this

Comment: Thank you very very much for the solution! It worked perfectly. That is really nice of you to even explain the situation. Perfect answer.